# How to stop tiling/repeating of images in ImageView?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-imageview

Please have a look at the below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/white">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_background"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@drawable/hhh" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/l22Parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/image_background"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/step18button1"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="39dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/step18textView"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="1"
            android:textSize="13dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/step18button2"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="39dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/step18button1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/step18button1"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/step18button1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="2"
            android:textSize="13dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/step18button3"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="39dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/step18button2"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/step18button2"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/step18button2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="3"
            android:textSize="13dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/step18button4"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="39dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/step18button3"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/step18button3"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/step18button3"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="4"
            android:textSize="13dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/step18button5"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="39dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/step18button4"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/step18button4"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/step18button4"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="5"
            android:textSize="13dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/step18button6"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="39dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/step18button5"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/step18button5"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/step18button5"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="6"
            android:textSize="13dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/step18button7"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="39dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/step18button6"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/step18button6"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/step18button6"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="7"
            android:textSize="13dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/step18button8"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="39dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/step18button7"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/step18button7"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/step18button7"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="8"
            android:textSize="13dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/step18button9"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="39dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/step18button8"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/step18button8"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/step18button8"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="9"
            android:textSize="13dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This generated the below UI

[image]

As you can see, the image is "titled". The original image is below

[image]

How can I stop this tiling ?

Comment: put ImageView inside LinearLayout. Set LinearLayout values to match height with weight as you do on ImageView. In ImageView set height and width to wrap_content. This should fix the problem with tiles.

Comment: @Rafal: Tried. Now the image got smaller.

Comment: smaller and still tiled or you just fixed the problem ?